# Text replacement with a button

Tags: javascript, html

Everything *looks* proper , yet when I click the button nothing happens.

```js
var typeRu;

function convert() {
  typeRu = document.getElementById("type-ru").innerHTML;
  typeRu.replace("b", "&#x431;");
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable id="type-ru" style="background:lightgray;padding:0.5em">merrybot</div>
<p>use <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd> for bold, <kbd>ctrl+i</kbd> for italic.</p>
<button onclick="convert()">convert</button>
```

Comment: What did you expect it to do? You're not using the new string the replace operation creates.

Comment: Might be a good idea to [review the documentation on `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `typeRu.replace("b", "&#x431;");` with `typeRu.innerHTML = typeRu.replace("b", "&#x431;");`

Answer (score 0):

what I did , just add this line under **convert()** function :

```
`document.getElementById("type-ru").innerHTML = typeRu.replace("b", "&#x431;");`
```

you were actually replace the string . but did not assign the new converted string to the **innerHTML** of id **type-ru**

```js
var typeRu;

function convert() {
  typeRu = document.getElementById("type-ru").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("type-ru").innerHTML = typeRu.replace("b", "&#x431;");
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable id="type-ru" style="background:lightgray;padding:0.5em">merrybot</div>
<p>use <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd> for bold, <kbd>ctrl+i</kbd> for italic.</p>
<button onclick="convert()">convert</button>
```